DialogContextError when handling files
I'm trying to handle files in bot framework in teams.
I have a dialog with this function :
async finalStep(stepContext) {
    if (stepContext.result && stepContext.result.length > 0) {
        stepContext.values.files = await Promise.all(stepContext.result.map(async file => ({
            filename: file.name,
            fileContent: await this.getFileContentInBase64(file.contentUrl)
        })));
    } else {
        stepContext.values.files = [];
    }

    const userProfile = await this.userState.get(stepContext.context, {});
    const aadObjectId = userProfile.aadObjectId;

    const finalData = {
        userId: aadObjectId,
        cet: stepContext.values.cet,
        sector: stepContext.values.sector,
        job: stepContext.values.job,
        requestType: stepContext.values.requestType,
        description: stepContext.values.description,
        files: []
    };


    const apiUrl = ''; // power automate url

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, finalData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const ticketId = response.data.id;

        await stepContext.context.sendActivity(t('dt_ticket.ticket_created', { ticketId }));

        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        const siteId = '';
        const driveId = '';
        const folderId = '';

        await this.uploadFilesToGraph(accessToken, siteId, driveId, folderId, stepContext.values.files, ticketId);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending data to the API: ', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }

    return await stepContext.endDialog();
}



async getFileContentInBase64(contentUrl) {
    const response = await axios.get(contentUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    return Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
}

async uploadFilesToGraph(accessToken, siteId, driveId, folderId, files, ticketId) {
    try {
        const client = Client.init({
            authProvider: (done) => {
                done(null, accessToken);
            }
        });

        for (const file of files) {
            //const fileContent = Buffer.from(file.fileContent, 'base64');

            // Create a small file with random content
            const fileName = file.filename;
            const fileContent = 'This is a random test content: ' + Math.random();
            fs.writeFileSync(fileName, fileContent);
            const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

            const fileUploadUrl = `/sites/${siteId}/drives/${driveId}/items/${folderId}:/${ticketId} - ${file.filename}:/content`;

            const response = await client.api(fileUploadUrl).put(fileBuffer);

        }
    } catch (error) {
        this.logDebug('Error uploading files to Graph', { error: error });
    }
}

I modify this to try to juste upload a little text file. On emulator localhost, it's working well, but when I'm using this code through teams bot, I have the following error :
Error: DialogContextError

And I don't have more informations.
The part which catch the error on index.js :
// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);

    // Log error to Application Insights
    telemetryMiddleware.telemetryClient.trackTrace({
        message: 'Error',
        properties: { error: error.toString() },
        severityLevel: 3 // Error
    });

    // Send a trace activity
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
    await context.sendActivity('Error : ' + error);
};

I can't figure out where the issue is, if you have some thoughts, would be great.


Error: DialogContextError


The actual error occurs in the  adapter.onTurnError  handler, which is a catch-all for unhandled errors.

The provided message ([onTurnError] unhandled error: ...) doesn’t give specific details about the issue.
Here, firstly I used ngrok as a tunnel to connect the development system to Teams.

After creating azure bot in portal configure app registration also. I have followed this ms-doc as a reference for uploading a file from teams.

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    bool messageWithFileDownloadInfo = turnContext.Activity.Attachments?[0].ContentType == FileDownloadInfo.ContentType;
    if (messageWithFileDownloadInfo)
    {
        var file = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];
        var fileDownload = JObject.FromObject(file.Content).ToObject<FileDownloadInfo>();

        string filePath = Path.Combine("Files", file.Name);

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(fileDownload.DownloadUrl);
        using (var sampleFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) 
        {
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(sampleFile);
        }

        var reply = MessageFactory.Text($"<b>{file.Name}</b> received and saved.");
        reply.TextFormat = "xml";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }
    else if (turnContext.Activity.Attachments?[0].ContentType.Contains("image/*") == true)
    {
        await ProcessInlineImage(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        string filename = "teams-logo.png";
        string filePath = Path.Combine("Files", filename);
        long fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
        await SendFileCardAsync(turnContext, filename, fileSize, cancellationToken);
    }
}


It checks if the message has attachments and if the first attachment is of type FileDownloadInfo.

If the message does not contain file with download information, it sends a default file card with a "teams-logo.png" file.



Zip the bot application and upload as shown in the above image.


Application running successfully and here I able to get the response from the bot.



Here I have uploaded the file as you can see below.


As you can see the bot is handling messages with files, images, and other types of messages appropriately.



I'v found a workaround using multipart/form-data, but I will try your answer, seem interesting, didn't know about the debugger
